# Why rails replaces value with updated_at instead of created_at

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails and mySQL in my project and trying to perform a simple console script:

```
Parent.all.each { |p| p.email_timestamp = p.created_at; p.save(validate: false); }
```

The thing is, that after this I find all the `email_timestamp` values equal to `updated_at` instead of `created_at`. What's wrong?

UPD. It actually works correct, but only the second time you run this script. First time it's working wrong, as described above. I've watched the SQL in log, and, as expected, it uses updated_at attribute.

Comment: What kind of field is `email_timestamp`? If it's a `DATETIME` it should be fine. If you're using the quirky old `TIMESTAMP` field you might be experiencing odd beheaviour related to that. Does `log/development.log` show what query is being run? Does that look correct?

Comment: You could try to call `Parent.all.each { |p| p.update_columns(email_timestamp: p.created_at) }` to avoid callbacks, although I see no currently reason why your call shouldn't work as expected.

Comment: Could you paste the output of `DESC parents` when you run in the MySQL client ?

Comment: UPD. It actually works correct, but only the second time you run this script. First time it's working wrong, as described above. I've watched the SQL in log, and, as expected, it uses updated_at attribute.